# Shiny R localhost Server not working

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying Shiny with R and loved the concept. I have been looking at many examples online and everything is working just fine. 
When i try to run the exact same example on my localhost server, I can see the text etc, tables but no images etc. It seems I have a JSON error in my browser. I dont understand why it is not happening when I browse online example. There is a png file in the example. Shiny struggles to generate this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you can successfully generate a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Do you use the same browser for the online example and localhost? Try to run localhost in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using Internet Explorer 8 or 9, or another browser that doesn't support websockets. Running Shiny applications without Shiny Server requires a fairly recent version of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, or IE10. (Probably Opera as well, but we don't test it.)

The online examples you've seen all use Shiny Server, which allows applications to be used using many older browsers.